# Is there a method to decrypt *.p7m file without key?

Tags: email, decryption

I need open `.p7m` message from my old PC, but I lost my old certs. Is there any method how to decrypt it without key?

Comment: If the crypto is good there is no way.

Comment: And if crypto isn't good?

Comment: It depends on the key size. S/MIME is old enough that it might use rsa keys less the 1024 bits, which are crack-able with enough effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, you could brute-force it. Decryption will take somewhere between "immediate" and "The end of the universe", so it depends on how lucky you are.

Practically, no. It's not going to happen.